# SqlBulCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable) results in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904)

Tags: sqlbulkcopy

As part of a annual process, there is a need to insert millions of records to DB.
I use SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer method to do so.

When processing even a less number of records it encounter below exception.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A severe error
>   occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be
>   discarded. A severe error occurred on the current command. The
>   results, if any, should be discarded. The statement has been 
>   terminated. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock,  Boolean asyncClose) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior  runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.RunParser(Bulk

Below is the code related:

```
utlConnection utlCoreDBConnection = HelperFunction.GetDBConnectionProperties("core");
string astrCoreDBConnection = utlCoreDBConnection.istrConnectionString;

SqlBulkCopy lSqlBulCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(astrCoreDBConnection);
lSqlBulCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
lSqlBulCopy.WriteToServer(ldtbActuarialActiveDetail);
```

Connectionstring from appsettings:

```
<connection ID="core" QueryType="SqlServerClient">
<dbstring value="Data Source=my-server;Initial Catalog=my-db;User ID=user;password=devpwd;TimeOut=1044;Persist Security Info=True;Asynchronous Processing=True"/>
<dbfactory value="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<dbnextquery value="select next value for sequence_name from sgs_system_management" />
<dbprevquery value="select previous value for sequence_name from sgs_system_management" />
<dbkeyquery value="select ident_current('name_of_the_table')" />
</connection>
```

Can anyone assist me with this exception?

Comment: Can you show more code. Specifically the set up of the connection

Comment: owen79, I have updated my question. GetDBConnectionProperties method will extract connection detail and set.

Comment: Doesn't look like you're opening your connection

Comment: The same code works fine in my dev machine. But fails in production. I guess the connection is taken care by writertoserver.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm stumped then, unless this is applicable http://www.andyfrench.info/2011/06/bulk-copy-full-text-and-severe-error.html

Comment: I have no clue of why am running this issue. Finally, I dropped this bulk insert...